# Error when adding vertical lines in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

So, I've got a large dataset (around 400 000 observations) of data from auctions. I'm trying to use ggplot to plot auction prices by day, while denoting year by color and month using vertical lines.

I have a POSIXlt vector that holds my dates, here is what I'm working with:

```
firstmonth<- c(1,32,60,91,121,152,182,213,244,274,305,335)

require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(bb, aes(saledate$yday, SalePrice))
p <- p + geom_point(aes(color = factor(saledate$year)), alpha = I(1/30)) #This plot works
p + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = firstmonth))
Error in data.frame(xintercept = c(1, 32, 60, 91, 121, 152, 182, 213,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 12, 401125
```

What's with this error? Why can't I get the vertical lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass a new data.frame to `geom_vline`:

```
library(ggplot2)

bb <- data.frame(SalePrice=rnorm(1000))
saledate <- data.frame(yday=1:1000,year=rep(1:10,each=100))

firstmonth<- c(1,32,60,91,121,152,182,213,244,274,305,335)

p <- ggplot(bb, aes(saledate$yday, SalePrice))
p <- p + geom_point(aes(color = factor(saledate$year))) #This plot works
p + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = firstmonth))
#error
df2 <- data.frame(firstmonth)
p + geom_vline(data=df2,aes(xintercept = firstmonth))
#works
```

Comment: (+1) So, basically, if you don't pass a new `data.frame`, then your mappings are limited to the number of points on `x` if you use `aesthetic`.. could you explain why? Also, why not simply do: `geom_vline(xintercept = firstmonth)` without the `aes` at all... [(since you're not overriding plot defaults)](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/geom_vline.html)?

Comment: What I mean by limited to number of points is this: `df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=10:1)` `p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line() + geom_point()` `p + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 11:20))` works where as, `p + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 11:25))` doesn't. As long as `aes(xintercept = .)` has the same number of points as x in aes, it seems to work.

Comment: Ya, this is right, but bizarre. As much as I love ggplot, stuff like this makes me feel I don't fully understand how it works. Which is frustrating. But thanks for the help.